# Add or remove data from the array

Tags: android

How can i add data into the String[] or remove line from the String[]?

```
//excerpt from class
public class Images {

public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
    "http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001a.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001b.jpg"};
}
```

Comment: You may want to user an `ArrayList` instead. Simply call add() and remove() and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

```
An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.
```

Instead you can use a [Vector](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html) or an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Some example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Inizialize a string:
    String path = "http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001b.jpg";

    // Inizialize the ArrayList:
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Add some values:
    s.add("http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001a.jpg");
    s.add("http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001b.jpg");

    //Remove first element:
    s.remove(0);

    //Remove the second element:
    s.remove(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove items:

```
public static String[] removeElements(String[] input, String deleteMe) {
    List result = new LinkedList();

    for(String item : input)
        if(!deleteMe.equals(item))
            result.add(item);

    return result.toArray(input);
}
```

add items:

```
imageUrls.add("test1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try List as below:

```
List<String> imageUrlList = Arrays.asList(imageUrls);
imageUrlList.add("http://localhost/webapp/mypic.jpg");
imageUrlList.remove("http://192.168.1.1/pictures/card/AA001b.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest you to do is using ArrayList to you can easly add and remove Strings from and into it

[Java doc ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)